# How to fadeIn parent div along with the child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

Currently I have a `div` container `#songs` with a `list` which is wrapped in parent `div` `#guts`. I am appending new list elements using jQuery `appendTo()` method. On append I use `fadeIn()` method, however that only animates the `#songs` `div`.

My question is, how can I animate the parent `div` at the same time so that once the new element is added the parent `div` `#guts` extends smoothly?

This is the example code:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="guts">
    <button type="button" id="add-btn">Add to playlist</button>
    <div id="songs">
        <ul>
            <li>Some list element</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-btn").click(function(){
        var new_el = "<li>New element</li>";
        $(new_el).appendTo("#songs").hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

And [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laurynasas/12jx9fgL/3/):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-btn").click(function(){
        var new_el = "<li style=margin-bottom:-20px; opacity:0;>New element</li>";
        $(new_el).appendTo("#songs").animate({'margin-bottom':'0', 'opacity':'1'}, 400);
    });
});
```

And CSS

```
.jumbotron {
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
background-color: #eee;
}
#songs li:not(:first-of-type) {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!